# Overlapping method calls (defined in a singleton object) from multiple threads causes problems?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, websocket, .net-core

Hello i have developed a websocket server and i would like to know if there is any problem in creating a service (which is used by the middleware)that has a method which is used for every websocket request.This method is async and it starts an infinite loop for the request (send-receive).
I would like to know if there is any problem memory-wise in the following scenario:

`Object A` is created once.
A has a method we'll call `MyInfiniteFunc`.
`MyInfiniteFunc` will start an infinite loop in its bowels.
If two other objects will call `A.MyInfiniteFunc()` (from different threads )more specifically on different `HttpContext`'s,if the two requests overlap  will there be any problem with `MyInfiniteFunc`?
I believe `MyInfiniteFunc` will be "instantiated" as many times it is needed or am i wrong?

P.S `MyInfiniteFunc` does not have any shared resource of which i have to take care of to be thread-safe.

***Concrete problem***:

**SocketMiddleware** -used by the appbuilder:

```
public class SocketMiddleware
    {
        public  byte[] ToSegment(string message) => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        ClientTracker clientTracker; //the socket clients tracker this is the object we're speaking of
        RequestDelegate next;
        public SocketMiddleware(ClientTracker tracker,RequestDelegate del)
        {
            this.clientTracker=tracker;
            this.next=del;   
        }
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if(!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                await this.next.Invoke(context);
                return;
            }
            await this.clientTracker.AddClient(context.WebSockets);

        }
    }
```

**SocketTracker**- this is the suspect which is dealing with all the opened sockets

```
  public class ClientTracker
        {
            ConcurrentDictionary<string, Client> clientMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Client>();

            public string CreateConnectionID() => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            public string GetIDOfSocket(WebSocket socket) => this.clientMap.First(x => x.Value.webSocket.Equals(socket)).Key;
            public Client GetClientByID(string id)
            {
                this.clientMap.TryGetValue(id, out Client client);
                return client;
            }
            public async Task AddClient(WebSocketManager manager)
            {
               using (WebSocket socket = await manager.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
               {
                 Client newClient = Client.CreateClient(socket, CreateConnectionID());
                 if(clientMap.TryAdd(newClient.clientID, newClient))
                 {
                   await ReceiveMessage(newClient);
                 }

                }
             }

            public async Task ReceiveMessage(Client client)
            {
                while (client.webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    WebSocketReceiveResult result = await client.ReceiveResult();
                    //dosomething with result...
                    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    {
                        await client.webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Client closed", CancellationToken.None);
                        break;
                    }
                    //send custom message 
                    await client.SendMessage("lala");
                }
            }
        }
```

**Client**- socketWrapper which performs all required operations on the socket and stores temporary data to be used by the tracker

```
public class Client
    {
        //Fields
        public readonly WebSocket webSocket;
        public readonly string clientID;
        public StringBuilder tempData;
        //Auxiliary
        private const int BufferSize = 1024 * 4;

        public static Client CreateClient(WebSocket socket, string id)
        {
            Client client = new Client(socket, id);
            return client;
        }

        public Client(WebSocket socket, string id)
        {
            this.webSocket = socket;
            this.clientID = id;
            tempData = new StringBuilder();
        }
        public async Task<WebSocketReceiveResult> ReceiveResult()
        {
            tempData.Clear();
            ArraySegment<byte> segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[BufferSize]);
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await this.webSocket.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);
            tempData.Append(BitConverter.ToString(segment.Array));
            return result;
        }

        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            await this.webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
        }

    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSingleton<ClientTracker>();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseWebSockets();
            app.UseMiddleware<SocketMiddleware>();
        }
```

As you can see i need the SocketTracker to perform businesslogic on multiple sockets . I am considering   accepting the socket in the middleware and then just add the socket to the tracker for tracking,and afterwards start the infinite loop in the middleware.But i am not sure about my first implementation.

Comment: Your implementation is fine.

Comment: So there is no problem with the implementation?Do you know where i can find out more about where method calls are allocated and how?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you mean with "method call allocation".

Comment: Well i mean where the variables and the code of the method is allocated .If lets say i have a static method that is called 100 times concurrently where is the code and data of the method stored and who manages it.

Comment: Method code is always stored in one place (whether static or instance method), doesn't matter how many times you call it. If by "data" you mean local variables - they are usually stored on stack of the calling thread. Same with method arguments - they are passed on stack of calling thread.

Comment: Ok so i would have no problem if every method "instance" is an infinite loop.Even if the object that defines it is instantiated only once .

Comment: Nope, because there is no such thing as "method instance" :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167549/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-evk).